# Global and local variable with the same name, unexpected value

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables

I have both a local and a global variable with same name.

```
int var = 10;
int main() {
    int var = var;
    printf("%d", var);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program gives this output: `0`

Why is that?

Comment: the local definition overrides the external. It's in local scope. How could the compiler know which is which?

Comment: I have to wonder how you missed: ***"warning: variable 'var' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization"***.

Comment: As well as **warning: declaration shadows a variable in the global scope**.

Answer (score 4):

The global variable has nothing to do with it, you can comment out that line of code. When the compiler finds a local variable with the same name as a variable in another, outer scope, the local variable will always be used.

Therefore both "var" in the expression `int var = var;` refers to itself: the local variable. It doesn't make any sense to initialize a variable to its own uninitialized value. The value will remain indeterminate and when you use the value in your program you invoke undefined behavior: anything can happen.

Comment: Technically, the compiler found `var` in the *same* scope.  Undefined behavior is invoked by the initializer itself already, and again in the `printf` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The `int var = var` in `main()` does not actually access the `var` at file scope.

The result is actually undefined behaviour, since it tries to access the value of the local `var` which has not been initialised.  So any result you get (zero, 42, reformatting your hard drive) is valid.

Try building your code with a different compiler, and you could well get a different output.

Out of curiosity, I compiled, built, and ran the same code (other than adding `#include <stdio.h>`) and the output I received was `41944322`.     The compiler on my current machine is gcc 4.8.1 (mingw).